# Delay in JavaScript slider

Tags: javascript

I'm coding a little slider with JavaScript and CSS. The slider works, but... in the transition of the last slide to the first I have troubles...

**CSS:**

```
.cambiaFoto{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    position: absolute;
}
.cambiaFotoActivo{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    position: relative;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="col-sm-5 alinear-der" ng-controller="cambiaFoto">
     <img src="img/productos/foto1.png" alt="" class="responsive-img cambiaFoto cambiaFotoActivo">
     <img src="img/productos/foto2.png" alt="" class="responsive-img cambiaFoto">
     <img src="img/productos/foto3.png" alt="" class="responsive-img cambiaFoto">
   </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function cambiaFotoCtrl($scope){

    function miniSlider(){
        var activo = document.getElementsByClassName('cambiaFotoActivo');
    activo = activo[0]
    siguiente = activo.nextElementSibling
    if (siguiente == null){
        siguiente = activo.parentNode.firstElementChild
    }
    activo.classList.remove('cambiaFotoActivo')
    siguiente.classList.add('cambiaFotoActivo')
    }

    setInterval(miniSlider, 5000)

}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/paw30e8b/

Somebody knows what is happening here?
Thanks!

Comment: can you create a codepen/fiddle of the code? or at least describe what kind of trouble you're facing

Comment: Don't use setInterval. Use requestAnimationFrame or setTimeout, failing that. Avoid setInterval unless it's trivial operations on a lengthy tick time as it won't stop and wait for the browser stack to clear. It just keeps ramping up calls to it regardless.

Comment: also.. it's good to have `;` in the end of each statement.

Comment: I put a jsfiddle. You can watch the error :). And thanks ManoDestra and Hugo for the answers :)

Comment: Oh Mano Destra, i don't know about requestAnimationFrame, I'm noob jeje, I'm gonna investigate :). But, for the solution in problem that you said, i use 
         interval = setInterval(miniSlider, 5000)
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
   clearInterval(interval)
  })

This way, I'm destroying setInterval from this scope and creates new one when I back this secction.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `position: relative;` from the `.cambiaFotoActivo` rule.

Elements with `position: relative` will use the natural page order which is next to the other images.

Comment: Well... the problem doing that is that my img move to the right... this is because my div container have auto height. Then override my elements on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Change `opacity: 0;` to `display: none;` and `opacity: 1` to `display: inline`.

```
.cambiaFoto{
    transition: all 0.8s;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
.cambiaFotoActivo{
    transition: all 0.8s;
    display: inline;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ke2q38d/1/

** Don't worry about how the functions are declared and the Jquery, just did that to make an easy example.

Comment: Yeah... this works pretty well... the problem in this case is that i don't have the opacity effect with css transition :P. I used to do that before and with jquery with fadeIn and fadeOut.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS should be adjusted this way:

```
.cambiaFoto{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    position: absolute;
}
.cambiaFotoActivo{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gmdwv4hg/

Basically you just have to set positioning to absolute on both classes.

Comment: On the page, I have 2 divs. The left div have the slide, the right div contains text and other thing. Both divs have auto height... so i can't put position absolute both, they gonna overlay each other

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm still wondering what happend here... why the problem is the last slide :(. I know the solution in this case, is a solution that not resolve at all my question. I want to fade out and fade in using opacity and transition. Works well in every slide... the problem is between the last and first slide. ¿Why? I don't know :P

But if you wanna know, I just delete the transition line in .cambiaFoto. Then the active slide disappear and the new fade in.